# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter implementing abstract method and override from superclass

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Using firebase for realtime data/chat app
My problem is:

Anonymous class derived from `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method `onBindViewHolder(VH, int, T)`.

Not understanding where I would implement abstract method

All gradle dependencies for firebase and google services are using the latest versions, and am using Android Studio 3.3

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(

                Users.class,
                R.layout.users_single_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                mUsersDatabase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, Users users, int position) {

                usersViewHolder.setDisplayName(users.getName());
                usersViewHolder.setUserStatus(users.getStatus());
                usersViewHolder.setUserImage(users.getThumb_image(), getApplicationContext());

                final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                usersViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(ListUsersActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        profileIntent.putExtra("from_user_id", user_id);
                        startActivity(profileIntent);

                    }
                });

            }
        };


        mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
```

This should be grabbing users information from the realtime DB in firebase and then placing in `viewholders` for later use. Anonymous class issue starts `= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>` and the `@Override protected void populateViewHolder` immediately below complains that method does not override method superclass.

Comment: You should implement in the same way `populateViewHolder` is implemented. In Android Studio, Ctrl+Insert -> Implement methods.

Comment: @Alex I didnt think it needed to be since it was inside the adapter...i even tried `code`public class FBRA extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>{`code` which broke it further

Comment: Have you tried the keyboars shortcuts I gave you?

Comment: I did, however nothing actually happened :/

Comment: No method was implemented?

Comment: When I went to the '= new firebaseRecyclerAdapter' after it highlighted, I hit crtl-insert as suggested, even for the @Override section, all it did was highlight the whole line. Nothing else got added or removed, I did try to clean and rebuild, even invalidate caches and restart....and the error still persists

Comment: Please add to your question the implementation you have used.

Comment: Even after making an overloaded method populateViewHolder i still recieve an error for @Override saying method does not override superclass

Comment: It means that you overrided the wrong one.

Comment: Alright...well i figured out the problem....partly due to using a newer gradle version of the firebase-ui-database. The above code works like a charm with at least firebase-ui-database 2.0.1, but once you hit 3.0 you need to make use of the FirebaseRecyclerOptions instead and then declare the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, use onBindViewHolder instead of onPopulateViewHolder (thanks @Alex Mamo)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: You need to implement this method `@Override public void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder holder, int position, Users users) { }` inside your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and initialize your recycler view items in there